# Cross Compiling Qt 5.10.1 for Raspberry Pi 3 not compiling webEngine

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile the Qt libraries for my raspberry pi. I actually got it working, but the module I needed the most for the project I was planing was not compiled. I need the webengine module.

Here is the output form the configure script:

```
Qt WebEngine: 
Embedded build ......................... yes   
Pepper Plugins ......................... no   
Printing and PDF ....................... no  
Proprietary Codecs ..................... no  
Spellchecker ........................... yes  
Native Spellchecker .................... no  
WebRTC ................................. no  
Use System Ninja ....................... no  
Geolocation ............................ yes  
Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes  
Use ALSA ............................... yes  
Use PulseAudio ......................... yes   
Optional system libraries used:  
  re2 .................................. no   
  icu .................................. no  
  libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . yes  
  opus ................................. yes  
  ffmpeg ............................... no  
  libvpx ............................... no  
  snappy ............................... no  
  libsrtp .............................. no  
  glib ................................. yes  
  zlib ................................. yes  
  minizip .............................. yes  
  libevent ............................. yes  
  jsoncpp .............................. yes  
  protobuf ............................. no  
  libxml2 and libxslt .................. yes  
  lcms2 ................................ no  
  png .................................. yes    
  harfbuzz ............................. yes  
Required system libraries:  
  fontconfig ........................... yes  
  dbus ................................. yes  
  nss .................................. yes  
  khr .................................. yes  
  glibc ................................ yes  
Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:  
  libdrm ............................... yes  
  xcomposite ........................... no  
  xcursor .............................. no  
  xi ................................... no  
  xrandr ............................... no  
  xtst ................................. no
```

As you can see, I have the required system libraries. But do I need everything that is listed under the Qt WebEngine headline?

EDIT: I found out why it was skiping the qtWebEngine:

```
V8 snapshot cannot be built. Most likely, the 32-bit host compiler does  not  work. Please make sure you have 32-bit devel environment installed, or        configure webengine with '-no-webengine-v8-snapshot'
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

I am not sure what the V8 snapshot is used for and why the installer couldn't use the 32-Bit compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67983

As you can see, this was fixed in Qt 5.11.1. Unfortunately there is another bug which will prevent you from compiling QtWebengine (workaround included): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65256